# JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512) Android

Tags: android

I am using slider Library is show me this error when i run and the program crashes
it was works fine and suddenly i run now not working really so strange problem.

[Here](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) is the code.

```
 '<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                    android:id="@+id/slider"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/parallax_image_height"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    custom:auto_cycle="true"
                    custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
                    custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
                    custom:pager_animation_span="1100" />'



        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115] JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115] local reference table dump:
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]   Last 10 entries (of 512):
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       511: 0x12c81c00 grand.myapp.MainPage
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       510: 0x12ea6280 java.lang.String "LinearLayout"
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       509: 0x12c81c00 grand.myapp.MainPage
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       508: 0x1302d000 com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       507: 0x1302c800 com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       506: 0x1302c000 com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       505: 0x1302b800 com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       504: 0x1302b000 com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       503: 0x1302a800 com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       502: 0x1302a000 com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]   Summary:
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]         2 of grand.myapp.MainPage (1 unique instances)
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       503 of com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout (503 unique instances)
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]         2 of java.lang.Class (2 unique instances)
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]         1 of java.lang.String[] (3 elements)
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]         4 of java.lang.String (4 unique instances)
        07-27 10:37:45.382: A/art(26770): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115] 
        07-27 10:37:46.722: A/art(26770): art/runtime/barrier.cc:90] Check failed: count_ == 0 (count_=-1, 0=0) Attempted to destroy barrier with non zero count
        07-27 10:37:46.722: A/art(26770): art/runtime/runtime.cc:370] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!
        07-27 10:37:46.722: A/art(26770): art/runtime/runtime.cc:370] 
        07-27 10:37:46.723: A/libc(26770): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 26770 (grand.myapp)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the problem solved really so strange thing 
i found that i created a layout with this name
slider_layout when i changed it everything worked fine :)